# How to make python editing work better with my virtual workspace?

Tags: python, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a extension that features a remote workspace. FYI, https://github.com/eliphatfs/naughty-k8s

However, when editing python files in remote there is only basic syntax highlighting support.
There is no completion according to contents, and no 'go to definition' functionality even the defs are in the same file. Yet these are working for a JavaScript.

I read this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-workspaces#language-extensions-and-virtual-workspaces

I don't expect the cross-file level support. Is there any way to make python support the single-file level?

Comment: do you need to install the Python extension to the remote workspace?

Comment: hi @starball, i am developing my own extension, and the remote workspace does not have a vscode installed, unlike the ssh remote. In fact, the remote workspace may not have a bound computation resource, and only some storage -- think of google drive, something like that.

Comment: have you implemented a `FileSystemProvider`

Comment: hi @rioV8 yes, i implemented a FileSystemProvider. Downloading, uploading and other file operations are all tested to be working well. Editing JS on the virtual workspace does have basic completion and go-to-def support. I wonder how to make it for python.

Comment: you have that with the PyLance team what they do special to files with a uri scheme that is not `file:`